# Getting count from complicated mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the count of unique questions from the following mysql statement but every time I try to add count(q.id) as questionCount the statement only returns one result. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34906/58

Hope somebody can help.

Steve

Comment: you mean one row result? or value in returned row is 1?

Comment: i try your problem and get result of 20

Answer (score 1):

Just edit 2nd line of your query to this one:

```
select
  count(distinct FinalQA.QUESTION_ID)   from.....
```

Comment: can you expand on that answer a little? 20 is wrong because there are only 5 unique questions. Each appears 4 times hence 20.

Comment: excuse me. my new answer is your solution. isnt this?

Comment: hi - no it's still returning only one question with one answer instead of 5 questions each with 4 answers like it does without the count added. Also question_id doesn't exist at the second line so returns 'unknown column' error

Comment: please tell me: what is the answer you want strictly, ok?

Comment: as you can see in the sql fiddler link the current result returns 20 rows which is correct. I want to get the count of unique questions which in the example at sql fiddler would be 5. Does that make sense? I could run the sql twice, once for the results and once for the count but i'm trying to do both with one call. Not sure if it's possible.

Comment: "count(distinct FinalQA.QUESTION_ID)"  returns 5, i cant understand you :(

Comment: yes but i want i'm trying to avoid running the query twice so I was thinking of returning ALL the data as it is now (20 rows) but with maybe an added column that would hold the number of unique questions (5). When I'm running the code on my site it's returning 240 rows so it seems like overkill to run it twice. I suppose I could just divide the number of rows by 4 to get the total number of unique questions but it seems like a hack....well a bigger hack than this :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want the total questions "stamped" on every row... for example you are auto-generating a test and want it to show "Out of 5 questions" in the output.  To simplify this, since you KNOW you want 5 questions via your WHERE clause, I would slightly adjust it to...

```
select
      FinalQA.*
   from
      ( select 
              5 as TotalQuestionsOffered,
              QWithAllAnswers.*,
              ... rest of query ) FinalQA
   where
      FinalQA.ARankSeq <= FinalQA.TotalQuestionsOffered
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is while I may ask for 5 there may not always be 5 questions which is why I want to know the exact number of questions that where found.